# How to use a retention policy for a specific mailbox?

Tags: exchange-server

I am new to scripting and want to learn it even more.
I want to delete emails in a specific mailbox that are older than 30 days. The mailbox contains alot of mails and will receive it every day. I need to clean it up multiple times. Is there somebody who can help me with it? The mailbox is named 'Portal'.

I thought this would work, but how can i modify it for a the specific Portal mailbox?

New-RetentionPolicyTag -Name "Portal" -Type All -MessageClass Email -AgeLimitForRetention 30 -RetentionAction DeleteAndAllowRecovery

I Hope somebody can help me. We use Exchange 2013.